# UEFN - Verse - Trying to make custom player class

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am trying to make a custom_player class complete with getters and setters, however when I run one the class's functions to get or set a value it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code for my game_manager_device:

```
using { /Fortnite.com/Devices }
using { /Verse.org/Simulation }
using { /Verse.org/Random}
using { /Fortnite.com/Characters }
using { /Fortnite.com/Game }
using { /Verse.org/Simulation/Tags }
using { /UnrealEngine.com/Temporary/Diagnostics }

spawner := class(tag){}
chest := class(tag){}

game_manager_device := class(creative_device):
    var CustomPlayers : [player]custom_player = map{}

        # Runs when the device is started in a running game
    OnBegin<override>()<suspends>:void=
        InitSpawners()

    InitSpawners():void=
        Spawners := GetCreativeObjectsWithTag(spawner{})
        for (Obj : Spawners):
            if (Spawner := player_spawner_device[Obj]):
                Spawner.SpawnedEvent.Subscribe(OnPlayerSpawned)
                
    OnPlayerSpawned(Agent : agent):void=
        Print("Player spawned")
        if (Player := player[Agent]):
            InitPlayer(Player)

    InitPlayer(Player : player):void=
        Print("initializing player")
        if:
            Agent := agent[Player]
            Fort := Agent.GetFortCharacter[]

        then:
            if (Existing := CustomPlayers[Player]){}
            else:
                Fort.EliminatedEvent().Subscribe(OnPlayerEliminated)
                CustomPlayer := custom_player{Player := Player}
                CustomPlayer.Init()
                if (set CustomPlayers[Player] = CustomPlayer) {}




    OnPlayerEliminated(Result : elimination_result):void=
        if:
            Killer := Result.EliminatingCharacter?
            Agent := Killer.GetAgent[]
            Player := player[Agent]
            CustomPlayer := CustomPlayers[Player]
        then:
            if (not (Result.EliminatedCharacter = Result.EliminatingCharacter?)):
                CustomPlayer.AwardElimination()

    OnPlayerLeftServer(PlayerLeaving : player):void=
        var NewCustomPlayerMap:[player]custom_player = map{}

        for (Key -> Value : CustomPlayers, Key <> PlayerLeaving):
            set NewCustomPlayerMap = ConcatenateMaps(NewCustomPlayerMap, map{Key => Value})
        
        set CustomPlayers = NewCustomPlayerMap
```

Here is the CustomPlayer class itself:

```
using { /Fortnite.com/Devices }
using { /Fortnite.com/Characters }
using { /UnrealEngine.com/Temporary/SpatialMath }
using { /Verse.org/Simulation }
using { /UnrealEngine.com/Temporary/Diagnostics }

custom_player := class<unique>():
    Player : player
    var CurrentElims<private> : int = 0
    var DamageNumber<private> : float = 0.0
    var TeamNumber<private> : int = 0 
    var SkillLevel<private> : int = 0
    var PlayerID<private> : int = 0

    SetDamageNumber(Damage:float):void=
        set DamageNumber += Damage

    GetDamageNumber()<transacts>:float=
        return DamageNumber

    SetSkillLevel(Skill:int):void=
        set SkillLevel = Skill      
    
    GetSkillLevel()<transacts>:int=
        return SkillLevel

    SetTeamNumber(Team:int):void=
        set TeamNumber = Team

    GetTeamNumber()<transacts>:int=
        return TeamNumber

    SetPlayerID(ID:int):void=
        set PlayerID = ID

    GetPlayerID()<transacts>:int=
        return PlayerID

    AwardElimination():void=
        set CurrentElims += 1

    GetElimCount()<transacts>:int=
        return CurrentElims
    
    Init():void=
        if:
            Agent := agent[Player]
            Fort := Agent.GetFortCharacter[]
```

And here is how I was trying to implement the code:

```
var CustomPlayers : [player]custom_player = map{}

... (irrelevant code here)
Print("Going into custom player code!")
if (CustomPlayer := CustomPlayers[AllPlayers[MyPlayerIndex]]):
    Print("Setting CustomPlayer team number...")
    CustomPlayer.SetTeamNumber(PlayerTeamNumber)
    CustomPlayerTeamText := CustomPlayer.GetTeamNumber()
    Print("Custom player team number {CustomPlayerTeamText}")
```

It prints the "Going into custom player code!" line is silent.

I know not many know UEFN/Verse on here but I find their forum pretty abysmal compared to this wonderful website and to be compeltely honest I need the reputation to help a user with a command that wouldn't work and I figured out why in an entirely different thread. But I really am struggling with this and help for it would be super appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question without tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
OnPlayerSpawned(Agent : agent):void=
    Print("Player spawned")
    if (Player := player[Agent]):
        InitPlayer(Player)
```

The logic within this doesn't look quite right. I think you should be checking if they have a key within the map, if not they are a new player and you should init them. If they have a key then they are just respawning, so don't wipe